# Set custom build number in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

I have version=x.y.z property in gradle.properties in my git repo. The custom build number needs to be version-build.counter 
We used the following custom script in TeamCity(running on Windows) to read this file and set the build number. Would like to know if anyone is aware of a better way to do this.

```
echo extracting version from gradle.properties
for /f %%%%i in ('type gradle.properties ^| find "version"') do set VERSION_PROPERTY=%%%%i
echo %%VERSION_PROPERTY%%
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%%%G IN ("%%VERSION_PROPERTY%%") DO SET VERSION=%%%%G
echo version = %%VERSION%%
echo "##teamcity[buildNumber '%%VERSION%%.%build.counter%']"
```

Comment: Define "better". Does your current way work?

Comment: Powershell may make it a bit more readable, though of course using the same trick as you're already using.

Comment: Yes Lasse V. Karlsen. The above technique works. The better way in my opinion would if there was a way I could have the key-value pairs from gradle.properties available that I could access in Teamcity without having to read, grep, parse etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for TeamCity that can read in parameters from a file and set them during the build. You shouldn't need to tailor your file in order for this to work for you, but you will have to have a variable in the build called version and reference this where you need it to be shown or consumed.

The plugin is called EnvInject - [Github repository](https://github.com/kannanekanath/teamcity-envinject-plugin/wiki)

Hope this helps